# How to make Entity Relationship Diagram of Mention case system?

Tags: database, erd

I want to make ERD of this table relation, actually I have made it, but it's still not correct. I don't know how to relate 2 same id (id_user and id_utarget) in table mention to tb users (id_user). Please help me guys, I've googled it, but I found nothing.

**Table Relation**

[image]

**ERD**

[image]

Anyone can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to record id_user in tb_mentions, since it can be obtained from tb_comments via id_comment.

However, if your problem is to indicate multiple relationships between the same two entity sets, then there's no problem at all:

[image: multiple relationships between same entities]

Note that your cardinality indicators show a many-to-many relationship between users and posts, and between users and comments. However, your tables show that these are one-to-many relationships.